# Where best to insert images using Scrivener for ebook/kindle etc

Tags: formatting, ebook, scrivener, artwork, kindle

My father wrote a book in Word and I have edited/formatted it so it looks clean in PDF, but now I know that was a bad idea because when we put the book on Kindle all the formatting was lost and the images/text are all over the place. I am now trying to reformat the book using Scrivener and I plan to compile it into a few different formats for ibook/ebook/kindle/whatever else there is!

We had originally inserted full-page images throughout the story, on the parallel page to their relevant text. So on an A4 PDF the sentence was interrupted at the end of a page, followed by a full page image on the next page, then the sentence would continue on the following page.

I'm wondering if that's possible to do now, or where else I should insert the images to avoid troubles with formatting when compiling?

I'm picturing someone using a tablet/book reader to read the book, and I'd like a full page of text, followed by a full page image, followed by a full page of text. But if ebook etc just have a flow on format with no 'pages' per say, how do I know where to put the image to ensure the text and image fills a whole page? or will the e-reader format it to fit? Is this even possible or do I need to reconsider my image placement and just have images at the start/end of the chapter? We also had some smaller images with text wrapped around them but I've read that's also not going to work in Scrivener?

Sorry for the long winded question - any answers hugely appreciated! I am a novice at this and just want to help my dad get his amazing story out there!

Comment: As someone who has read ebooks where someone clearly went to a lot of effort to break the free flow of text, I feel the need to ask, why force images that were full pages to still be full pages? Why not just have the image occur after the line they came after in the book, and before the next one, or maybe have it happen after that sentence or paragraph? If I'm viewing in a pageless mode, forcing a paged view on me in a few places will be very jarring, and may possibly even reduce the utility of the work.

Answer (score 2):

I had some similar issues/wants and found that adding images (and a lot of other formatting options) in an open-source e-book editor 'Sigil' to be a huge improvement of the quality, layout, form, etc., of my e-book.  I compiled the e-book in Scrivener with only the text itself included in the Epub e-book I created and then opened it using Sigil where I added images and some formatting.

It is an extra step but one I found worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a page break under Edit –> Insert –> Page Break. There should be a key shortcut too depending on your system.